# Can I place a PHP File within an angular app?

Tags: php, angular

I've got my angular app on my web server and I need the app to send an email!

Most simple way I can think is to just send data from Angular to a PHP file which can just execute PHP Mail.

Trouble is, I've made a directory within the app called `/php`, and inserted a `.php` file. When I aim at the `.php` file, it takes me to my app but with no data or anything. I really just want it to execute the `.php` file.

Now I do understand, the app is running in express server which will not run PHP, so is there a way around this?

Thanks (I'm running Angular 6)

Comment: the usual approach is an ajax call from angular, not a direct link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a single mail sending script that works based off information sent to it via $_POST, so when I need to send mail from anything I just generate a post to my super script with the correct form fields/values in it. I can post from Java, Angular/JS stuff, PHP, curl on the command line, whatever.

For your situation, I would use a similar approach.  Add in some authentication to be sure it is your angular app that is sending the post, and it should be relatively quick and easy.

BUT... that PHP script must run on a webserver wtih properly configured mail system for the `mail()` call to work

Comment: Thanks, am I right in saying mail() doesn't use a Mail server?

Comment: No, on a *nix system the internal mail server needs to be configured, on a Windows machine the SMTP server needs to be specified.